# O que pode estar causando requisições duplas ao PHP?

Tags: php, symfony-2

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em Symfony2 e durante o processo de homologação o cliente pegou um erro no qual os alertas do sistema ficam se repetindo.

O código utilizado é este:

```
$objManager     = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$objRepositorio = $objManager->getRepository( 'CIDSegurancaBundle:Usuario' );
$objUsuario     = $objRepositorio->find( $id );

if ( !$objUsuario ) {
  throw $this->createNotFoundException( 'Usuario nao encontrado para id ' . $id );
}

$objUserType = new UsuarioType( $objManager );
$objUserType->setIsEdit( true );
$objUserType->setUrlListagem( $this->generateUrl( 'usuarioListar', [ 'page' => 1, 'manterFiltro' => true ] ) );
$objUserType->setUrlListarEG( $this->generateUrl( 'usuarioAjaxListarEG' ) );
$objUserType->setUrlListarProcessos( $this->generateUrl( 'processoAjaxListarByMacroProcesso' ) );
$objUserType->setUrlListarSubProcessos( $this->generateUrl( 'subProcessoAjaxListarByProcesso' ) );

$objForm = $this->createForm( $objUserType, $objUsuario, [ 'attr' => [ 'id' => 'formUsuario' ] ] );

$objForm->handleRequest( $request );

$objUsuarioLogado = $this->getUser();
$objUsuario->setUsuarioAlteracao( $objUsuarioLogado );
$objUsuario->setDatAlt( System::getNow() );

if ( $objForm->isValid() ) {
  $objManager->persist( $objUsuario );
  $objManager->flush();

  $this->addFlash( 'info', 'Usuario alterado com sucesso!' );
  return $this->redirectToRoute( 'usuarioListar', [ 'page' => 1, 'manterFiltro' => 1 ] );
}

return $this->render( 'AppBundle:AcessControl:alterar.html.twig', [
  'title'  => 'Alterar Usuario',
  'form'   => $objForm->createView(),
  'perfis' => Perfil::getPerfisDisponiveis()
] );
```

O erro que estou recebendo é que as mensagens "FLASH" estão aparecendo repetidas na páginas seguinte.
Ao alterar um usuário o cliente aleatoriamente recebe a mensagem: `Usuário alterado com sucesso` duas vezes ou até mais.

Aparentemente a requisição está sendo processada duas vezes.

Fiz vários testes locais e não consegui de forma alguma reproduzir o erro, então estou imaginando que isto está relacionado a alguma configuração do navegador ou do servidor do cliente.

Para homologação o cliente está utilizando o *Google Chrome 31.0.1650.57 m*

Localmente para os testes estou utilizando o *Google Chrome `40.0.2214.111 m*

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode estar causando o problema?

**Edição - 28/07/2015 às 08:30**

alterar.html.twig

```html
{% extends 'AppBundle:util:form_cad.html.twig' %}
{% block javascript %}
  {% javascripts '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/AcessControl/cadastro.js' output='js/usuario/cadastro.js' %}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
  {% endjavascripts %}

  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.perfil = {
    {% for nome, id in perfis %}
    {{ nome }}: '{{ id }}',
    {% endfor %}
    };
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

form_cad.html.twig

```
{% extends 'AppBundle::base.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form 'AppBundle:util:form.template.html.twig' %}
{% import "AppBundle:util:macro_form.html.twig" as macro %}

{% block conteudo %}
  {% spaceless %}
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
        <div class="panel panel-primary box-shadow-filter">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title text-center">{{ title }}</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body" id="formulario-cadastro">
            {% block panel_body %}
              {{ form_start(form) }}
              {{ form_widget(form) }}
              {{ form_end(form) }}
            {% endblock %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

base.html.twig

```
{% spaceless %}
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}"/>

    <title>{% block title %} {{ project_name }} {% endblock %}</title>

    {% stylesheets 'bundles/app/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.min.css'
    'bundles/app/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/layout.css'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/sweetalert.min.css'filter='cssrewrite' output='css/main.css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
    {% endstylesheets %}

    {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}

    {% javascripts
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/plugin/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/plugin/bootstrap.min.js'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/plugin/jquery-ui.min.js'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/plugin/jquery-mask.min.js'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/plugin/sweetalert.min.js'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/plugin/jquery.dataTables.min.js'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/util/modal.js'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/util/setup.js'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/util/util.js'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/util/processo.js'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/*.js'output='js/main.js' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}

    {% block javascript %}{% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
  {% block navbar %}
    {% block navbar_main %}

      <div class="navbar-main">
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center logo-top">
          {% block image_top %}
            <a href="{{ path('homeListar') }}">
              <img src="{{ asset('bundles/app/images/logo_cliente_azul.gif') }}"/>
            </a>
          {% endblock %}
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 text-center project-name">
          {% block project_name_top %}
            {{ project_name }}
          {% endblock %}
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 pull-right"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm pull-right">
          {% block user_top %}
            {% if app.user is not null %}

              <div class="divFotoUsuarioLogado">
                {% set nome = app.user.nomUsuario|split(' ') %}
                <img class="img-circle" src="http://URL-REMOVIDA/foto/{{ app.user.username }}.jpg"
                     title="" alt="" width="40" height="40"/>
              </div>
              <div class="divNomeUsuarioLogado">
                Ol&aacute;,<br/>
                <span class="text-uppercase">{{ nome[0] }}</span>
              </div>

            {% endif %}
          {% endblock %}
        </div>

      </div>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block navbar_menu %}
      {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Menu/Menu:accessMenu')) }}
    {% endblock %}

  {% endblock %}

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

    {% include 'AppBundle:util:session-alert.html.twig' %}

    {% block modal %}
      {{ include("AppBundle:util:modal-alert.html.twig") }}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block conteudo %}

    {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
{% endspaceless %}
```

Comment: Posta a view para que a comunidade possa analisar.

Comment: não pode ser o usuário clicando 50x no botão salvar?

Comment: Talvez. Questionei o cliente sobre isto e ele me informou que não. Acredito que tenha algum erro no HTML gerado ou no próprio Browser.

Comment: Olha o código-fonte gerado para o navegador. Se o javascript responsável pela ação repetir, a ação é executada duas vezes :)

Comment: +1 porque usa symphony :) rsrsrsrs

Comment: Poste a parte do template onde você imprime as mensagens do flashbag, por favor. :)

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? Se sim, poste a resposta e feche a pergunta, por favor :)

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti, consegui resolver. O problema eram tags form com action vazio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percebi que algumas tags form estavam com seu action vazio.
Colocando corretamente o action nos formulários sanou o problema.